# How to create kafka compacted topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a `Kafka` application that has a `producer` who produces messages to a topic. A `consumer` then takes the messages from the topic, does some logic to the given messages and then produces them to another topic.
I'm using `ProducerRecord` and `ConsumerRecords`.

I want my app to create 2 `compacted topics` and then use them. If the `compacted topics` already exist, just display a message and continue.

My `SimpleProducer` class:

```
  package com.kafkatest.demo;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
public class SimpleProducer extends Thread{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      String topicName = "nodesTopic";
      String key = "Key1";
      String value = "Value-1";

      String key1 = "Key2";
      String value1 = "Value-2";



      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
      props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");         
      props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

      Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <>(props);

      ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
      producer.send(record);


      ProducerRecord<String, String> record2 = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key1,value1);
      producer.send(record2);


      ProducerRecord<String, String> record3 = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
      producer.send(record3);


      ProducerRecord<String, String> record4 = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
      producer.send(record4);


      ProducerRecord<String, String> record5 = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
      producer.send(record5);


      ProducerRecord<String, String> record6 = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
      producer.send(record6);
      producer.close();

      System.out.println("SimpleProducer Completed.");
   }
}
```

My SimpleConsumer class:

```
   package com.kafkatest.demo;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class SimpleConsumer extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties props1 = new Properties();
    props1.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
    props1.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");         
    props1.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <>(props1);

    Duration duration = Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    String topicName = "nodesTopic";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "consumer-tutorial");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props); 

    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

    try {
        while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        consumer.beginningOffsets(consumer.assignment());
          ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(duration);
          for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println(record.offset() + ": " + record.value());
            System.out.println("Record: " + record.value().toLowerCase());
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record1 = new ProducerRecord<>("forecastTopic", "Key", record.offset() + ". " + record.value().toLowerCase());
            String a = "" + records.count();
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record2 = new ProducerRecord<>("forecastTopic", "Key", record.offset() + ". " + a);
            producer.send(record1);
            producer.send(record2);
          }
        }
      } finally {
        producer.close();
        consumer.close();
      }

    }

}
```

When I run `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic forecastTopic --from-beginning` and I run my producer a couple of time, I get

```
0. value-1
0. 6
1. value-2
1. 6
2. value-1
2. 6
3. value-1
3. 6
4. value-1
4. 6
5. value-1
5. 6
6. value-1
6. 6
7. value-2
7. 6
8. value-1
8. 6
9. value-1
9. 6
10. value-1
10. 6
11. value-1
11. 6
12. value-1
12. 6
13. value-2
13. 6
14. value-1
14. 6
15. value-1
15. 6
16. value-1
16. 6
17. value-1
17. 6
18. value-1
18. 6
19. value-2
19. 6
20. value-1
20. 6
21. value-1
21. 6
22. value-1
22. 6
23. value-1
23. 6
24. value-1
24. 6
25. value-2
25. 6
26. value-1
26. 6
27. value-1
27. 6
28. value-1
28. 6
29. value-1
29. 6
30. value-1
30. 6
31. value-2
31. 6
32. value-1
32. 6
33. value-1
33. 6
34. value-1
34. 6
35. value-1
35. 6
36. value-1
36. 6
37. value-2
37. 6
38. value-1
38. 6
39. value-1
39. 6
40. value-1
40. 6
41. value-1
41. 6
42. value-1
42. 6
43. value-2
43. 6
44. value-1
44. 6
45. value-1
45. 6
46. value-1
46. 6
47. value-1
47. 6
48. value-1
48. 12
49. value-2
49. 12
50. value-1
50. 12
51. value-1
51. 12
52. value-1
52. 12
53. value-1
53. 12
54. value-1
54. 12
55. value-2
55. 12
56. value-1
56. 12
57. value-1
57. 12
58. value-1
58. 12
59. value-1
59. 12
60. value-1
60. 6
61. value-2
61. 6
62. value-1
62. 6
63. value-1
63. 6
64. value-1
64. 6
65. value-1
65. 6
66. value-1
66. 6
67. value-2
67. 6
68. value-1
68. 6
69. value-1
69. 6
70. value-1
70. 6
71. value-1
71. 6
72. value-1
72. 6
73. value-2
73. 6
74. value-1
74. 6
75. value-1
75. 6
76. value-1
76. 6
77. value-1
77. 6
78. value-1
78. 6
79. value-2
79. 6
80. value-1
80. 6
81. value-1
81. 6
82. value-1
82. 6
83. value-1
83. 6
```

I put the `log.cleanup.policy=compact` in the `server.properties` file, but it doesn't seem to work, because I have all the 83 offsets in the topic.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I found `log.cleanup.policy=compact`, but I don't know where to put it. Is it somewhere in the `Kafka` config ?

Comment: You should place it under `/etc/kafka/server.properties`.

Comment: Does it matter where I place it in this file?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I check if it is compacted. As far as I understood it, `compacted topics` are like `KTable` in the `Kafka Streams` (it only saves the last value for the key). But when I start `kafka consumer` on the topic from the terminal, it writes all the values from the beginning. I'm sorry for so much questions, I started working with Kafka yesterday for the first time, also if it is easier for you, I can edit my question and add the code and the consumer output

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Do you want all topics to be compacted? If so, do not put it in the server properties... You need to create your topic as compacted beforehand, and compaction only applies on closed Kafka segments, which are 1GB large by default, so with 83 simple messages, you  won't see it happening

Comment: My goal is to have a `Key` of type` Lon`g (represents a `company ID`) and a `Value` of type `JGraph<Card>` (custom class with a lot of variables) and I want every time I change the `Card` values for a given `company ID`, to run the compaction for the given company ID. That way I don't have multiple Graphs for 1 key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command:

```
kafka-topics --topic topic_name --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --config "cleanup.policy=compact" --create
```

Answer (score 12):

Just in case somebody finds this helpful, this is the actual CLI command to use if you want to make a specific topic compacted, and don't want to set all your topics to compacted at the server level.

```
bin/kafka-topics --alter --topic my_topic_name --zookeeper my_zookeeper:2181 --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

Assuming the above is being run from the confluent base directory.  I believe you have to change the command to call `bin/kafka-topics.sh` if using just a regular Apache Kafka distribution.

Comment: This is deprecated now. Use kafka-topics.sh instead.

Answer (score 4):

When you set `log.cleanup.policy=compact` in server.properties, it will be the default policy when creating new topics. If you change server.properties after creating your topic, your topic configuration won't change.

You can alter your topic configuration to set `cleanup.policy=compact`

As compaction is made by log cleaner, you may want to set specific `delete.retention.ms` on your topic as default retention is 24 hours.

Last, compaction doesn't occur on active segment.
see [Kafka Log Compaction not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513527/kafka-log-compaction-not-starting)

Comment: I deleted all the `kafka logs` and started new with the `cleanup.policy=compact` in `server.properties`, created the topics and it is not working again, 
These are my settings: 
`log.cleaner.enable=true`

`min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01`

`log.cleanup.policy=compact`

`segment.ms=100`

`delete.retention.ms=100`

Comment: When you say it is not working, you mean not matter how long you wait, your consumer never consumes only two records corresponding to the two keys in the topic ?

Answer (score 1):

Create compact kafka topic command:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic foo --config "cleanup.policy=compact"
```

Describe topic ( where you can see cleanup.policy=compact )

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic foo
```

Please note that you should not keep cleanup.policy in server.properties.