# Under what conditions does Compaction start processing in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have run into a situation where I turned on compaction for a topic, started sending messages to that topic, yet the topic continues to maintain older records by key even though lots of time has passed. I read that there are very specific circumstances that have to take place in order for compaction to kick in. What are these circumstances? Are they documented somewhere because I have not been able to locate it.

I am trying to gauge the possibility of having a log compacted topic that maintains the latest values by key that consumers can utilize if they want to get the current state of data (and not ALL the historical data), but it seems like compaction may not be the best option since it doesn't seem to kick in immediately and will only kick in if a large amount of data is present within the topic.

Comment: You can read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550457/kafka-log-compaction-returns-two-records-with-the-same-key, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256783/kafka-only-subscribe-to-latest-message/54257047#54257047, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298063/kafka-compaction-for-de-duplication/54298919#54298919, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513527/kafka-log-compaction-not-starting, https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_compactionbasics

Comment: Maybe you should stream all data to a topic and then use streams API. Streams API offers local data store which might be something that you would like to use. I don't know much about Ktable but I think it might be helpful at some degrees.